# Computational tool for identification of activity cliff

Tags: molecular-structure

Are there computational tools for identification of activity cliff between two analog compounds? This [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11030-015-9609-z)  list chemotypes that with a high propensity to induce activity cliff.

[image]

Comment: This may fit well on the new Materials Modeling SE: https://materials.stackexchange.com/